# How to use Comparison operator with text data?

Tags: php

How to use Comparison operator with text data ?

This is my table

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/51c/zBed4I.png

And this is my code.

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE number >= '3' AND number <= '5' order by id asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$datas=mysql_fetch_array($result);{
$id = stripslashes(str_replace('\r\n', '<br>',($datas['id'])));
}
?>
```

After test code, I will get result id `1` and `2`

How can i do that ?

Comment: it's a bad practice to store (comma or what ever) seperatet "ids" in a field ... better you use a secound table to store relations ..

Comment: **Learn to indent your code.**

Comment: If you normalize your Database properly you'll automatically get rid of this problem. You violated the 1NF (**only atomic values**, no repeating groups ). http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Answer (score -1):

You could always change your table structure so that one value per column is stored.
BUT work-around for your table structure could be this:

instead of '='use LIKE
moreover, use something like this:

where number like '*[3-5]*'

please lookup for regex in sql, I am not very good in regex.
but the basic idea is to use LIKE query and try match any pattern that starts with anything but has atleast either 3 or 4 or 5 in between and then has anything after that.